# Shortcut for accessing a specific file with CLI

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line-interface

When using Command line interface, do people use some clever method for accessing specific files. E.g., I am inside a folder and want to open a specific file or folder with a long name (my_awesome_holiday_pictures_from_China). Rather than typing that long name, can I use some shortcut? Like maybe the file is sorted as fourth in a folder and I can just type in that number. Is there a common way of doing this? Or am I being super lazy?

I'm using MacOS Terminal.

Comment: You tried pressing the TAB?

Comment: oh, man.. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To expand on C1sc0's answer (maybe for newbies), type the first letter of the long file name, "m", then press tab. If no other file name begins with "m", the entire file name will be printed to the command line. If another file name also begins with "m" (or a longer duplicate substring), only the part of the file name that is the duplicate substring of all file names that start with the substring will be printed, and then you will need to type one or more disambiguating characters, then press tab again. Repeat until the entire file name is printed. This saves so much time, I must do it dozens of time a day, even for short file names. The tab trick also works for paths, another great time saver.

Another great time saver is history expansion. If you have a long command line that you have previously executed and need to execute again it's in the command history list of commands previously typed. At the command line type "history" to see the history list. Or type "his" and "tory" will be filled in for you (on OS X anyway).

You can execute a command from the history list using the syntax !n where n is the line number from the history list.

To find out more, type "man bash" on the command line, and read the entire document. It will change your life.